# iOS 7: Dragging in UITableView / delaysContentTouches seems not working

Tags: uitableview, scroll, ios7, draggable, touchesbegan

I have an iPad App with draggable content in a UITableView...The tableView is scrollable horizontally and full of dragable images (subclass of UIImageView with overwritten `touchesBegan:` etc.)

Till iOS 7 the `tableView.delaysContentTouch=YES;` of the UITableView works as expected and the app was able to differentiate between a horizontal scrolling in the tableView (fast movement with the finger over the tableview) and dragging of an element inside the tableviews contentView (hold finger a second on the draggable till the tableview forwards the touch to `touchesBegan:` of the UIImageView subclass in the contentView.

Now under iOS 7 scrolling is nearly impossible, because the dragging of the content immediately fires. Code wasn't changed.

Anybody expierenced something similar and found a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

delaysContentTouches is not working in iOS7 and 7.02, this seems to be a bug, you can use touchesBegan and touchesCancelled (which is sent if the user scrolls) as a workaround to handle your touchEvents the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I was trying to solve the issue with workarounds. I was having the Gold Master IPSW installed in my iPhone 5. Then I updated to iOS 7.0.2. 
Today my phone was having problems to activate and I had to restore the phone (now it restores to the latest iOS version). The issues with the scrolling disappeared. So, I assume it was related to the old ipsw not updated properly to ios 7.0.2.